# HTTP client: Disconnected with error: -114 Lua

Tags: http, https, lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm trying to comunicate with thingspeak using my nodemcu. I'm using lua and i'm trying to push data using a get request but i get(literally...) this error:

```
> HTTP client: Disconnected with error: -114
HTTP client: Connection timeout
HTTP request failed
```

I don't know why. I'm connected to my wifi and here is my code:

```
url = "https://api.thingspeak.com/update.json?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&field1=" .. temp
print(url)
http.get(url, nil, function(code, data)
    if (code < 0) then
      print("HTTP request failed")
    else
      print(code, data)
    end
  end)
```

Here's my modules:

```
crypto,dht,file,gpio,http,mdns,mqtt,net,node,pwm,sjson,spi,tmr,tsl2561,uart,websocket,wifi,tls
```

Any ideas? I don't know what to do.

Comment: This is likely caused by the fact that you are using an encrypted HTTP connection. I suggest you read up on the limitations at https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/http/ and the TLS module docs.

Comment: I read this so do you think it's because thingspeak's certificate chains is too big and i run out of memory? In this case my idea to avoid the problem is good, 'cause i use http protocolo in lan to comunicate with a raspberry zero w as hub. Instead about mqtt why i get the error "Not authotized"? If i try to use mqtt with my android app or my python script it works good. Maybe is because it use ssl/tls even in mqtt? So maybe the same problem will occur in any case

Answer (score 0):

I use 'http.post' for uploading my sensor readings to ThingSpeak:

```
  http.post('http://api.thingspeak.com/update',
     'Content-Type: application/json\r\n',
     '{"api_key":"'..tsapikey..'","field1":"'..field1..'","field2":"'..field2..'","field3":"'..field3..'","field4":"'..field4..'"}',
     function(code, data)
        if (code < 0) then
           print("HTTP request failed")
        else
           print(code, data)
        end
     end)
```